# Jspm init command fails in Visual Studio 2015 RTM empty asp.net 5 project

Tags: git, npm, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, jspm

Do you have any idea what might be wrong with the setup? I've followed the instructions from http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/18/using-jspm-with-visual-studio-2015-and-asp-net-5.aspx but the init command fails. See the printout beneath:

```
C:\Dev\test-git\WebApplication5\src\WebApplication5>jspm init
Package.json file does not exist, create it? [yes]:
Would you like jspm to prefix the jspm package.json properties under jspm? [yes]
:
Enter server baseURL (public folder path) [./]:./wwwroot
Enter jspm packages folder [wwwroot\jspm_packages]:
Enter config file path [wwwroot\config.js]:
Configuration file wwwroot\config.js doesn't exist, create it? [yes]:
Enter client baseURL (public folder URL) [/]:
Which ES6 transpiler would you like to use, Traceur or Babel? [babel]:Babel
ok   Verified package.json at package.json
     Verified config file at wwwroot\config.js
     Looking up loader files...
       system.js
       system.src.js
       system.js.map
       es6-module-loader.js
       es6-module-loader.js.map
       es6-module-loader.src.js

     Using loader versions:
       es6-module-loader@0.16.6
       systemjs@0.16.11
     Looking up npm:babel-core
     Looking up npm:babel-runtime
     Looking up npm:core-js
     Updating registry cache...

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (1).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (1).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (1).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (2).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (2).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (2).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (3).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (3).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm, retrying (3).
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm
     Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git fetch --all &
& git reset --hard origin/master"
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read c844d6e9846d16de721ccd148535c9245216fb49
     error: Could not read 71e140765fe258dee3dc3fcaf3a2d0770f80175c
     error: Could not read 5b2fac719faf2b57f48e1282ec673281b1d9d0f8
     error: Could not read 10b982b70fead5e7e8436571a77c72df38c0694e
     fatal: pack has 85 unresolved deltas
     fatal: index-pack failed
     error: Could not fetch origin

         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
         at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

err  Error downloading loader files.

err  undefined

C:\Dev\test-git\WebApplication5\src\WebApplication5>
```

Comment: I got a fix from the jspm team:
clearing the jspm cache - jspm cc fixed it.
[Github issue thread](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/955)

Comment: if you want to see better support for jspm in Visual studio vote on https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/7352635-jspm

Answer (score 1):

I got a fix from the jspm team: clearing the jspm cache running:

```
jspm cc
```

More info at [Github issue thread](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/955)